# R - histogram data in aggreagation

Tags: r

With a data frame like below:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE),
                 prop1 = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                 prop2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 6, replace = TRUE),
                 prop3=sample(3:6, 6, replace = TRUE))

> df
  id prop1 prop2 prop3
1  2     A FALSE     4
2  2     B  TRUE     4
3  3     A FALSE     6
4  1     B  TRUE     5
5  3     A FALSE     3
6  3     B FALSE     4
```

I need to do an aggregation by `id` such that ,for each col `prop1` to `propN`, a histogram data is generated as follows.

For each `id`,

- `prop1` need to capture ratio of number of discrete values - `"A"`s , `"B"`s for all records with same `id` which can be accessed via names like `prop1[["A"]]` & `prop1[["B"]]`
- `prop2` need to capture ratio of number of discrete values - `"TRUE"`s , `"FALSE"`s for all records with same `id` which can be accessed via names like `prop1[["TRUE"]]` & `prop1[["FALSE"]]`
- `prop3` need to capture ratio of number of discrete values - `"3, 4, 5, 6"` for all records with same `id` which can be accessed via names like `prop1[["3"]]`,  `prop1[["4"]]`, `prop1[["5"]]`, `prop1[["6"]]`

How to get the aggregation for `prop1` to `propN` done in the above format - using base R

Update:Adding output representation.

I'm not certain about the right data type to represent the output and various components in the output. However a spreadsheet view of the output would be as follows. In realty the output desired is in a form such that it can be used as a look-up table for the distribution on an `id` basis for further computation.

[image: spreadsheet view of output]

Comment: why base-R? `dplyr` etc can be so better!

Comment: If you want do draw a histogram of prop3-values for each combination of id, prop1 and prop3, then `tapply(df$prop3, INDEX=list(df$id,df$prop1, df$prop2), FUN=hist)` should help. If not, please explain further and give a desired output for your example.

Comment: @joel.wilson it is quite fashionalbe to answer everything with dplyr these days, but the decision between `dplyr` and `data.table` is still open. In my opinion, it is worthwhile to learn the "core" of `R` before getting to dependend on the package of the day. People have solved this kind of questions for decades without additional packages.

Comment: @Bernhard thanks.. got it !

Comment: Could you please add your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea which uses a custom function defined as follows:

It splits the data frame based on the `id` and applies the formula (`prop.table(table(...))`) for finding the ratio. The `n` acts as an index so as to identify for which column you need the ratio. If `n` is 2 for example, then `fun1` will apply the formula of finding the ratio to column 2 for each element of the list (effectively for each `id`). Finally, we apply the function via looping through `2:ncol(df)` (so in your case 2:4) in order to get the ratio for all columns of interest, for each id.

```
#convert to factors to make sure you will get 0 frequencies with table as well
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.factor)

fun1 <- function(df, n){as.data.frame(t(sapply(split(df, df$id), function(i) 
                                                         prop.table(table(i[,n])))))}

data.frame(id = unique(sort(df$id)), 
           do.call(cbind, sapply(2:ncol(df), function(i)fun1(df, i))))

#   id        A         B FALSE. TRUE.        X3        X4  X5       X6
#1  1 0.0000000 1.0000000    0.0   1.0 0.0000000 0.0000000  1 0.0000000
#2  2 0.5000000 0.5000000    0.5   0.5 0.0000000 1.0000000  0 0.0000000
#3  3 0.6666667 0.3333333    1.0   0.0 0.3333333 0.3333333  0 0.3333333
```

Another way to structure this, would be to create a list and name each element of the list with the column names of your original df. i.e.

```
l1 <- sapply(2:ncol(df), function(i)fun1(df, i))
names(l1) <- names(df[-1])

#so you can extract each one separately,

l1[['prop1']]
#          A         B
#1 0.0000000 1.0000000
#2 0.5000000 0.5000000
#3 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Comment: is it possible to get the column names as in the dataset and use another data structure (list, dataframe ?? ) to store the distribution of discrete values of a column for each `id` - the reason for this is eventually the distribution for each column which hold a property need to be used for further computations some where else.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: let me try again - in the output you've provided, we have lost the original column name - so there isn't a way to look up for a particular original column's distribution for an `id`. If the original column names were kept - like `prop1`, `prop2` so on and a data structure like `data.frame` or `list` is used to hold the histogram data, the output is well re-usable

Comment: Updated my answer. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: I think this is good. could you please add a comment on what `fun1` is doing ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
library(reshape)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1],as.factor)
# second, rearrange vars in a named vector
df <- melt(df,id=c("id"),variable_name = "prop")
df$prop <- as.factor(df$prop)

#third, make the histograms with ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

h <- ggplot(df,aes(x=id)) 
h + geom_bar(stat="count", aes(fill=id)) + facet_grid(~ prop + value)
```